# Why can't I compille AMQP-CPP example code?

Tags: c++, compilation, g++, amqp

I am trying to compile some of the example code from the AMQP-CPP README file: [AMQP-CPP](https://github.com/CopernicaMarketingSoftware/AMQP-CPP).  But for some reason I am unable to compile the example given for TcpConnection.  Everything looks fine, but I keep getting:

```
g++ --std=c++11 -Wall -lamqpcpp -lpthread -ldl -c main.cpp -o main.o

main.cpp:20:1: error: 'channel' does not name a type
 channel.declareExchange("my-exchange", AMQP::fanout);
 ^~~~~~~
main.cpp:21:1: error: 'channel' does not name a type
 channel.declareQueue("my-queue");
 ^~~~~~~
main.cpp:22:1: error: 'channel' does not name a type
 channel.bindQueue("my-exchange", "my-queue", "my-routing-key");
```

The code in question:

```
//Main.cpp
#include "MyTcpHandler.h"
#include <amqpcpp.h>
#include <amqpcpp/linux_tcp.h>
#include <amqpcpp/linux_tcp/tcpchannel.h>

// create an instance of your own tcp handler
MyTcpHandler myHandler;

// address of the server
AMQP::Address address("amqp://guest:guest@localhost/vhost");

// create a AMQP connection object
AMQP::TcpConnection connection(&myHandler, address);

// and create a channel
AMQP::TcpChannel channel(&connection);                                                                                                                                                                      


// use the channel object to call the AMQP method you like
channel.declareExchange("my-exchange", AMQP::fanout);
channel.declareQueue("my-queue");
channel.bindQueue("my-exchange", "my-queue", "my-routing-key");
~
```

```
// MyTcpHandler.h
#include <amqpcpp.h>
#include <amqpcpp/linux_tcp.h>

class MyTcpHandler : public AMQP::TcpHandler
{
    /**
     *  Method that is called by the AMQP library when a new connection
     *  is associated with the handler. This is the first call to your handler
     *  @param  connection      The connection that is attached to the handler
     */
    virtual void onAttached(AMQP::TcpConnection *connection) override
    {
        // @todo
        //  add your own implementation, for example initialize things
        //  to handle the connection.
    }

    /**
     *  Method that is called by the AMQP library when the TCP connection 
     *  has been established. After this method has been called, the library
     *  still has take care of setting up the optional TLS layer and of
     *  setting up the AMQP connection on top of the TCP layer., This method 
     *  is always paired with a later call to onLost().
     *  @param  connection      The connection that can now be used
     */
    virtual void onConnected(AMQP::TcpConnection *connection) override
    {
        // @todo
        //  add your own implementation (probably not needed)
    }

    /**
     *  Method that is called when the secure TLS connection has been established. 
     *  This is only called for amqps:// connections. It allows you to inspect
     *  whether the connection is secure enough for your liking (you can
     *  for example check the server certicate). The AMQP protocol still has
     *  to be started.
     *  @param  connection      The connection that has been secured
     *  @param  ssl             SSL structure from openssl library
     *  @return bool            True if connection can be used
     */
    virtual bool onSecured(AMQP::TcpConnection *connection, const SSL *ssl) override
    {
        // @todo
        //  add your own implementation, for example by reading out the
        //  certificate and check if it is indeed yours
        return true;
    }

    /**
     *  Method that is called by the AMQP library when the login attempt
     *  succeeded. After this the connection is ready to use.
     *  @param  connection      The connection that can now be used
     */
    virtual void onReady(AMQP::TcpConnection *connection) override
    {
        // @todo
        //  add your own implementation, for example by creating a channel
        //  instance, and start publishing or consuming
    }

    /**
     *  Method that is called by the AMQP library when a fatal error occurs
     *  on the connection, for example because data received from RabbitMQ
     *  could not be recognized, or the underlying connection is lost. This
     *  call is normally followed by a call to onLost() (if the error occured
     *  after the TCP connection was established) and onDetached().
     *  @param  connection      The connection on which the error occured
     *  @param  message         A human readable error message
     */
    virtual void onError(AMQP::TcpConnection *connection, const char *message) override
    {
        // @todo
        //  add your own implementation, for example by reporting the error
        //  to the user of your program and logging the error
    }

    /**
     *  Method that is called when the AMQP protocol is ended. This is the
     *  counter-part of a call to connection.close() to graceful shutdown
     *  the connection. Note that the TCP connection is at this time still 
     *  active, and you will also receive calls to onLost() and onDetached()
     *  @param  connection      The connection over which the AMQP protocol ended
     */
    virtual void onClosed(AMQP::TcpConnection *connection) override 
    {
        // @todo
        //  add your own implementation (probably not necessary, but it could
        //  be useful if you want to do some something immediately after the
        //  amqp connection is over, but do not want to wait for the tcp 
        //  connection to shut down
    }

    /**
     *  Method that is called when the TCP connection was closed or lost.
     *  This method is always called if there was also a call to onConnected()
     *  @param  connection      The connection that was closed and that is now unusable
     */
    virtual void onLost(AMQP::TcpConnection *connection) override 
    {
        // @todo
        //  add your own implementation (probably not necessary)
    }

    /**
     *  Final method that is called. This signals that no further calls to your
     *  handler will be made about the connection.
     *  @param  connection      The connection that can be destructed
     */
    virtual void onDetached(AMQP::TcpConnection *connection) override 
    {
        // @todo
        //  add your own implementation, like cleanup resources or exit the application
    } 

    /**
     *  Method that is called by the AMQP-CPP library when it wants to interact
     *  with the main event loop. The AMQP-CPP library is completely non-blocking,
     *  and only make "write()" or "read()" system calls when it knows in advance
     *  that these calls will not block. To register a filedescriptor in the
     *  event loop, it calls this "monitor()" method with a filedescriptor and
     *  flags telling whether the filedescriptor should be checked for readability
     *  or writability.
     *
     *  @param  connection      The connection that wants to interact with the event loop
     *  @param  fd              The filedescriptor that should be checked
     *  @param  flags           Bitwise or of AMQP::readable and/or AMQP::writable
     */
    virtual void monitor(AMQP::TcpConnection *connection, int fd, int flags) override
    {
        // @todo
        //  add your own implementation, for example by adding the file
        //  descriptor to the main application event loop (like the select() or
        //  poll() loop). When the event loop reports that the descriptor becomes
        //  readable and/or writable, it is up to you to inform the AMQP-CPP
        //  library that the filedescriptor is active by calling the
        //  connection->process(fd, flags) method.
    }
};
```

I'm sure this is a fundamental misunderstanding of some basic c++ stuff, but I'm at a complete loss

Comment: @ted, I get the same exact error.  The error at the top is the only thing I am getting from this.  The command used is: g++ --std=c++11 -Wall -lamqpcpp -c main.cpp -o main.o

Comment: @ted So I apologize, but I messed up pretty badly.  I inserted the error message from a different version of the code during me frantically trying to figure out the issue.  And the code I inserted didn't include the pointer creation.  So that delta caused some confusion.  It has been edited in the question, but I am not using a pointer to do this.  But its worth noting that even when I do use a pointer it still gives the same error

Comment: "_I inserted the error message from a different version_" - I figured that out and deleted my comments and answer :-D Now, minimize the code needed to replicate this. Make a [mcve] so we can try it out by copying your code and trying to compile it as-is (with no need to add anything).

Comment: @TedLyngmo I think it is at is most minimum form (minus removing all the comments in the MyTcpHandler.h file)  I have the header and cpp file sitting in the same directory and i run 
g++ --std=c++11 -Wall -lamqpcpp -lpthread -ldl MyTcpHahdnler.h main.cpp -o main
I had, during debugging, moved the MyTcpHandler.h implementation into a seperate cpp file (which changed the g++ command) but that didn't seem to work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to call member functions on a global object outside a function (in global context):

```
channel.declareExchange("my-exchange", AMQP::fanout);
channel.declareQueue("my-queue");
channel.bindQueue("my-exchange", "my-queue", "my-routing-key");
```

Put those calls inside `main()`

Comment: Whoa, I spent a couple hours trying to figure this out.  Banging my head on the table, starting to think I didn't understand C++ anymore... and i forgot to put the code into a function.  I have no idea how I didn't see this.... I should not be allowed to touch a computer @TedLyngmo

Comment: @cojae :-D Happens to me too. It's usually a sign of having been at it for too long.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the error message, what is the type of "channel"?

```
error: 'channel' does not name a type
```

Looks like you are using arrow method to set channel but the compiler does not know what type the channel is.

Comment: Channel is an AMQP::TcpChannel.  Not a pointer, The code I put up originally had the ->s because I forgot to take them out.  I had attempted to make it a TcpChannel* to see if that got any different results. It didn't